# Spring JPA Data - Save method won't update

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I am using the following code to replicate data from one datasource to another one:

```
public T find(ReplicadorKey key) throws NoSuchElementException {
        return (T) sourceRepository.findById(key).orElseThrow();
    }

    public T save(T item) throws Exception {

        try {
            T persistedItem = find(item.getId());
            BeanUtils.copyProperties(persistedItem, item); //Merges data from 'item' to 'persistedItem'
            return sourceRepository.save(persistedItem); 
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            return repositoryOrigem.save(item);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }

    }
```

The "T" is a class that extends from "Replicador":

```
@Data
@Entity
@IdClass(ReplicadorKey.class)
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class Replicador implements Serializable {
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private String rep001c; //Ambient
    
    @Id
    private Long rep002n; //SEQ Identifier

    private String rep003c; //Action Identifier
    private Integer rep004n; //Replication status
    private Date rep005d; //Last update
}
```

This is the "ReplicadorKey.class":

```
@Data
public class ReplicadorKey implements Serializable {
        
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String rep001c;

    private Long rep002n;

    public ReplicadorKey(){}

    public ReplicadorKey(Replicador item) {
        this.setRep001c(item.getRep001c());
        this.setRep002n(item.getRep002n());
    }
    
}
```

But, when I call sourceRepository.save() method inside "try", it throws a ConstraintException related to fields Rep001c and Rep002n. The log shows that Hibernate it is trying to INSERT a new register instead UPDATING the existent one.

Please, what am I missing in this part to be able to UPDATE instead of INSERT if the object already exists in the table?

Thank you.

Comment: @OlehKurpiak that's what `@IdClass` is for. Hibernate supports composite keys which are not using `@EmbeddedId` - at least since version 4.

Comment: Does `BeanUtils.copyProperties(persistedItem, item)` change the Id of `persistedItem`?

Comment: @JensSchauder no, it does not change the id keys. I used vscode debugger to check that and it doesn't change.